# matlab workspace accessing multiple variables with similar names

Tags: matlab

I have a list of files that have data ...

```
    foo1.txt
    foo2.txt
    ...
    fooN.txt
```

I extract the data in these files

```
    foo1
    foo2
    ...
    fooN
```

I now want to pass these variables to a function

```
   for i = 1:N
       % This is what I want: asdf = fooi
       function(asdf)
   end
```

I tried sprintf, and also

```
    asdf = ['foo' num2str(i)]
```

But these make the variable asdf a char, instead of a double like fooi.

Thanks in advance.

-gsandhu

Answer (score 2):

Immidiate solution

```
asdf = eval( sprintf('foo%d',i) );
```

However this is **not** a good practice in general.
What you should do is read the files into cell-elements `foo{1}` will have the contents of `foo1.txt`, `foo{2}` will have the contents of `foo2.txt` and so on. This way you can simply access `foo{i}` and get the data you need.

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: 2.) And more importantly, thank you for the cell array suggestion.

Comment: @gsandhu I'm happy I could assist. If this solution works for you, please consider "accepting" it be clicking the "V" icon beside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function

`eval(['foo' num2str(i)])`